# VMWare vCenter: "incorrect username or password" when connecting to host

Tags: vmware-esxi, installation, vmware-vsphere, vmware-server, vmware-vcenter

- I have an existing vCenter server (v5.0) with two existing ESXi servers.
- I recently installed ESXi v5.1 on two new servers.
- I configured their hostnames, IPs, DNS, gateway, etc. and both pass their management network test.
- I can also ping them both from my machine by both ip and hostname.
- I can login to the local machines just fine from the console using "root" and a password that is well-known to me.

In my existing vCenter, when I attempt to add the new server to a cluster, I receive the error **"A general system error occurred: Timed waiting for vpxa to start"** -- and the specific event listed is "cannot connect [myservername]: **incorrect user name or password**."

- I have tried adding the server with and without a FQDN
- I've tried with a license key and in evaluation mode
- I've tried those steps for both of the new servers I installed ESXi onto.

Not sure where to even begin here. Hoping to avoid a support ticket; thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must upgrade vCenter to 5.1 in order to add a host with ESXi 5.1. No vCenter version prior to 5.1 supports ESXi 5.1.

### References

- [Add an ESXI 5.1 host in vcenter server 5.0](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/417689) [[VMWare Communities]](http://communities.vmware.com)
- [VMWare Product Interoperability Matrix](http://partnerweb.vmware.com/comp_guide2/sim/interop_matrix.php) [[VMWare Compatibility Guide]](http://partnerweb.vmware.com/comp_guide2/search.php)

Comment: I ran into this as well.  Upgrading vCenter first is the way to go.

Comment: That's definitely the issue. We'll work on that. Thanks; hadn't realized a minor version increment would be such a breaking change. Lesson learned!

Comment: Same here... I'm finding I need to read the instructions more carefully with new VMWare products.